# maftools tcgaCompare plot: x-axis labels getting clipped

Tags: r, maftools

I have a *{maftools}* plot:

whatever I try to save that completely I see the down part of plot is trimmed like

[image]

I have tried both save as pdf and save as image options which did not differ

Any suggestion please?

Plot comes by this code

```
tcgaCompare(maf = laml,cohortName = "Cohort",rm_zero = FALSE,decreasing = TRUE,logscale = TRUE,primarySite = TRUE,col = c("grey30", "red"),medianCol = "black")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to increase the outer margins of plot.

```r
par(oma=c(7,0,0,0))
tcgaCompare(maf = laml, primarySite = TRUE)
```